When building a fiber optic interferometer what methods are used to reduce microphonic effects?
When building a fiber optic interferometer what methods are used to reduce microphonic effects? I'm familiar with a few methods such as: enclosing the interferometer under a sound dampening cover, suspending the apparatus on vibration isolators, encapsulating the fiber components in polymers or epoxy resin, selecting components (couplers, connectors, isolators, etc.) with low sensitivity to vibration. Are there any other methods?

This may sound ridiculous, but I find that in the physics lab "whatever works hands on" is usually the best answer. Since I never had this particular problem I can't give you a "hands on" recipe that I know is guaranteed to work.
Going with first principles, however, it should be obvious that to reduce acoustic coupling one should suck the air out of the room since it supports sound transmission.
Failing that one could think about actually detecting the sound with a microphone, correlating the interferometer output with the microphone signal and then by using an adaptive filter algorithm one could subtract the properly filtered acoustic signal from the interferometer signal. This method works quite well for manufacturers of noise cancelling headphones and achieves noise reduction on the order of 20-40dB, sometimes more.
Whether it's a good use of your time (are you writing a thesis?) to reinvent noise-cancelling gear and algorithms is a question only you and your supervisor can answer.
Maybe the most valuable advice you could get is from certain employees of the US Navy and corporations in the military industrial complex that are concerned with the design of nuclear submarines. I am sure they could tell you a lot of very valuable tricks... but then they might have to shoot you.

Thank you for suggestions. Connecting a microphone and using adptive filter is definitely something to consider, however, before I go this route I'd like to make my interferometer as resistant to vibration as possible so I can get the best signal to noise ratio.

@Jimski I am pretty certain that trying a bunch of soft baby blankets and different grades of foam insulation will yield much faster results than digital signal processing. The vacuum thing was only halfway joking, by the way. LIGO is operating at 1e-9 Torr for good reason. If you want experts for this problem who won't shoot you... the LIGO folks are probably hard to beat in terms of interferometer isolation.

Using vacuum may have been a half-joke but it may actually be possible to implement it on a small scale https://ibb.co/gt6LtVG . And it has an additional advantage of reducing thermal conductivity.
